# Facebook API returns empty fields

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am creating a WPF application on C# using the Facebook API. This application is to find accounts by name and print information about the accounts. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT uid, name, books, education, email, music, movies 
FROM user WHERE CONTAINS('Anton Petrov')
```

But I have a problem. The API is only returning `uid` and `name` fields. Other fields is empty. How can I get this fields?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fetch every details of a user. We have to ask for permissions to get the details other than the basic ones.